# How to display an element underneath another element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place my social and email links found with a ul `additional-menu`, to be displayed under my site's logo and tagline. I seem to be struggling getting it underneath. At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

The code below is like so:

```css
.additional-menu {
  list-style-type:none;;
  margin: 0;
  position:relative;
  clear:both
}

.additional-menu li{
  display:inline-block;
}

.ast-header-html-1{
  position:relative;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="ast-site-title-wrap">
   <h1 class="site-title" itemprop="name">
      <a href="https://puffpastrydelights.com/" rel="home" itemprop="url">
      Pastry Delights
      </a>
   </h1>
   <p class="site-description" itemprop="description">
      Made with love, served with pride
   </p>
</div>
<div class="ast-builder-layout-element ast-flex site-header-focus-item ast-header-html-1" data-section="section-hb-html-1">
   <div class="ast-header-html inner-link-style-">
      <div class="ast-builder-html-element">
         <ul class="additional-menu">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/PastryDelights2020" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/puff_pastry_delights/" class="fa fa-instagram" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:puffpastrydelights@gmail.com" class="fa fa-envelope" target="_blank"></a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The CSS you posted is not the correct styling for this bit of code, can you update your post with the correct CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the whole thing with div that has `display:flex` and `flex-direction: column`

```css
.wholeThing {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.firstBit {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wholeThing">
  <div class="firstBit">
    <div class="logo"><img src="http://placekeanu.com/250" /></div>
    <div class="tagline">Keanu is breath taking</div>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    social one two three
  </div>
</div>
```

`